# Can I use civi import/export to update a set of activities and attach them to cases?

Tags: civicase, data-import

I'm updating a set of activities in CiviCRM.

previously these have been recorded ad-hoc on the database, but in future they'll be part of a case.

To update previous details and bring them into the case structure can I update an activity via api importer and stipulate a case id? So that after import the old activities will show as part of a case?

Comment: i don't think this has anything to do with 'drupal-views' so perhaps that Tag should be removed

Comment: Are there a lot that you want to do in bulk or can you just use file-on-case individually?

Comment: It's possible to do that as I wrote some code to do exactly that, but unsure whether it's possible to do it via the api importer.

Comment: Thanks petednz. Fixed that. Bad proof-reading on my part.

demerit- don't know yet. currently changing the system so some current and backdated cases may need updating. Will look at updating one byone as a fall back.

Andy, the very notion of writing code fills me with existential dread.

Comment: And currently I'm getting the simple word "Error" when accessing the importer. Waiting for tech support to get that working again.

Comment: More thoughts on this, Craig. You have a bunch of activities for a contact, who has 2 or more cases.  How do you know which activities should be attached to which case?  This is a problem which might be solvable if there were a very few but not for many.  But maybe this is not your situation.

Comment: Hi Andy- if we have multiple cases for an individual I think they will be rare. And probably update via file on case, as per Demerit's suggestion.

Comment: Got the api importre extension upgraded so I can now at least access it.

Case ID is available as an import field for activities so bulk update looks feasible.

I'll give it a run through in a few weeks time (still finalising case activity/ data structure). And post what I did as an answer.